# how can I add a url for my template in django python?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

i use a **template** im my django homepage.(http://127.0.0.1:8000/)
I linked statics files in static folder and formed like {% static .....}
when i path it in urls in the main page it work correctly.
but when I give it an slug like 'p/' it doesn't work.
because it search for statics in p folder:
"GET /p/static/post/js/scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2598"
my app name is "post" .
please help?"

```
<link href="{% static 'post/css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'post/css/fontawesome-all.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'post/css/swiper.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'post/css/magnific-popup.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'post/css/styles.css'%}" rel="stylesheet">             
'
```

this my setting:
`STATIC_URL = '/static/   MEDIA_URL = '/media/' STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`

this my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',include('post.urls')),]'
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    }),
]
```

this is my views:
'''

```
from django.shortcuts import render  
from django.http import HttpResponse  
from .models import app_post  
def hello(request):
html = "<h>salam django<h>"
return HttpResponse(html)  
def page(request):
return render(request,'post/index.html')
```

'''
this is my app urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('',page,name = 'page'),
path('h/',hello,name = 'hello'),
]
```

Comment: Post some code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

and then run command `python manage.py collectstatic`